# Creating a macro with infinte arguments

Tags: rust

```
struct Foo{
    value: i32
}
impl Foo{
    fn get_and_change_value(&mut self) -> i32{
        let v = self.value;
        self.value = 42;
        v
    }
}
//glue_code_macro
fn main(){
let mut f1 = Foo{value:1};
let mut f2 = Foo{value:2};
let mut f3 = Foo{value:3};
let v: Vec<i32> = glue_code_macro!(f1,f2,f3);
}
```

I want to create the `glue_code_macro` which takes `n` variables and creates a vector. I don't think that I can achieve this with a normal function because I have a mutable reference and I would be unable to change its content.

In my head it would expand to

```
let v = {
  let v1 = f1.get_and_change_value();
  let v2 = f2.get_and_change_value();
  let v3 = f3.get_and_change_value();
  vec!(v1,v2,v3)
}
```

Is this possible? If yes how would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible. Add this to the top of your module:

```
#![feature(macro_rules)]
macro_rules! glue_code_macro(
    ($($element:ident),*) => (
        vec![$($element.get_and_change_value(),)*]
    )
)
```

The macro guide explains how it works: http://doc.rust-lang.org/guide-macros.html